# Ripple emulator - node.js

Tags: cordova, ripple

I can't start ripple emulate. Here is the error:

```
ripple emulate could not find cordova as a local module. expecting to find it installed globally
```

Cordova is installed with the following command: `npm install cordova`

I'm working on windows 8.1 64bit

Comment: install cordova with ```npm install -g cordova```

Answer (score -2):

I had the same message but i understood it not as an error but as an information message.
ripple could be installed as a global app (c:\program...) or in the cordova project directory.